# Duplicate Albums in Gracenote

Tags: gracenote

While using `Gracenote's File ID`, I stumbled across two tracks which are from the same album. While the name of the album returned by Gracenote is the same, the `Album IDs` are different.

Following are the album ID's returned by Gracenote.

```
185260847-BA617E1ECCDAB2E29942C7F1725425C9

167355618-1938FB9BFCA9B7994EC306088451D007
```

If you run `ALBUM_FETCH` on the two album id's mentioned above, you will see, they have same name, album art, number of songs.

Any idea on how to deal with this scenario.

Thanks for your help.

Best, 
Anurag

Comment: Yes, even i have encountered this in certain cases. But not sure on how to handle this.